# secure images (gmail)

Tags: html, security, image, gmail

I was wondering how to keep images secure on my website. We have a site that requires login then then user can view thousands of different images all named after their ID in the database.

Even though you need to login to view the images the proper way...nothing is stopping a user from browsing through the images by typing `<website-director>/image-folder/11232.jpg` or something.

this is not the end of the world but definitely not ideal. I see that to stop this facebook just names the images something much more complicated + stores them in hashed folders.

Gmail does a very interesting thing, their image tags looks like this:

```
<img src=/mail/?attid=0.1&disp=emb&view=att&th=12d7d49120a940e5>
```

I thought the src attribute has to contain a reference to an image??...how does gmail get around this?

This is more for educational purposes at this point, as I think this gmail scheme might be overkill for our implementation.

Thanks for your feedback in advance,
Andrew

Answer (score 2):

> I thought the src attribute has to contain a reference to an image?

GMail is referencing an image. It's just being pulled dynamically, probably based off of that `th=12d7d49120a940e5` string.

Try browsing to http://mail.google.com/mail/?attid=0.1&disp=emb&view=att&th=12d7d49120a940e5

Instead of it being a direct path to its location on the server's filesystem, it uses a dynamic script (the images may even be in a database, who knows).

Answer (score 1):

Besides serving up an image dynamically from your webapp, it's also possible to use a webapp to dynamically *authorize* access to static resources that the webserver will serve -- commonly by putting the files somewhere that the webserver has access to, but not mapped to any public URI, and then using something like `X-Sendfile` (lighttpd, Apache with mod_sendfile, others), `X-Accel-Redirect` (nginx), `X-Reproxy-File` (Perlbal), etc. etc. Or with FastCGI you can configure an application in a FastCGI "authorizer" role rather than a content provider.

Any of these will let you check the image being authorized, and the user's session, and make whatever decision you need to, without tying up a proceses of your backend application for the entire time that the image is being sent to the client. It's not universally true, but usually a connection to the backend app represents a lot more resources being reserved than a connection to the webserver, so freeing them up ASAP is smart.

Answer (score 0):

The code that runs after this GET request is issued:

```
/mail/?attid=0.1&disp=emb&view=att&th=12d7d49120a940e5
```

outputs an image to the browser. Something doesn't have to be named with a `.jpg` or `.png` or whatever ending to be considered an image by a browser. This is how captcha algorithms are able to serve up different images depending on a value in the id. For example, this link:

http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c=03AHJ_VusfT0XgPXYUae-4RQX2qJ98iyf_N-LjX3sAwm2tv1cxWGe8pkNqGghQKBbRjM9wQpI1lFM-gJnK0Q8G3Nirwkec-nY8Jqtl9rwEvVZ2EoPlwZrmjkHT7SM32cCE8PLYXWMpEOZr5Uo6cIXz1mWFsz5Qad1iwA

Serves up this image:

[image]

So the answer really is to just obfuscate your image names/links a bit like Facebook does so that people can't easily guess them.